# Lombok @SneakyThrows performance

Tags: java, weblogic, lombok

personally before  i decide to use new technology ,i check the Garbage collector performance in the case using new technology and without it then compare results.
in this case when i used @SneakyThrows in following situations :
weblogic and load with 10000 thread  ,every call to class  raised exception ,in the case without  @SneakyThrows jprofiler snapshot  shows better performance,this may be wrong result but i am trying to repeat it and send result to Lombok team.
my question is that, has any body same experience?